# Is there a way to add a default while still keeping type restrictions in a function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, function, types

If I have this code as follows, how do I make it so `name` has to be a `string` but also has a default of "person", something like what follows:

```
function greet(name = "person": string) {
  console.log(`Hello ${name}!`);
}

greet("Bob"); //Should return "Hello Bob!"
greet(1) //Should return error about having the wrong type
greet() //Should return "Hello person!"
```

It returns an error instead of working as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your type annotation for `name`:

```
function greet(name: string = "person") {
  console.log(`Hello ${name}!`);
}
```

Or just infer the type:

```
function greet(name = "person") {
  console.log(`Hello ${name}!`);
}
```

**Edit:** If you want `name` to be either `string` or `number`, use an [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types):

```
function greet(name: string | number = "person") {
  console.log(`Hello ${name}!`);
}

greet("Bob"); // "Hello Bob!"
greet(1); // "Hello 1!"
greet(); // "Hello person!"
```

Comment: Follow Up Question: what if instead of "person" I had a number, would it still work

Comment: No, what I mean is if I have                                                                                   
 name:  string  = 5 //Or like some other number   Edit: I want the person to be able to input only strings but if they don't input anything I want name to be a number

Comment: That's what my update is about. `string | number` means, that `name` can be a `string` or a `number`. Therefore its default value can also be a `string` or a `number`.

Comment: @KobyK "I want the person to be able to input only strings but if they don't input anything I want name to be a number" You can achieve this with overloads: https://tsplay.dev/m3Be1N